Boolean intersect deltes all geometry including within the region of intersection

In this scene there are two objects: tower (highlighted in the image below) and tower_fill (the middle bits).

They both have all transforms applied and are boolean intersected with the same cuboid. This intersection trims tower to within the volume of the cuboid. In the above image, the modifier is disabled for tower_fill but if I enable it, tower_fill completely disappears.

Here are the modifiers:


Why don't both meshes get trimmed the same way?

I think you just have to enable Self Intersection on the faulty tower_fill. Also, I'm not sure your mesh (tower_fill) is manifold. If not, it is expected from the boolean modifier to not work as it should.

Is it a mesh? I don't think it would work with curves or instances

“The cuboid” is not shown in the image, unless you meant the two cuboid railings on the sides of the lattice that are unaffected by the Boolean? Please add that to your post.

@Lutzi enabling self intersection worked, but why should that matter at all here?

@spraff No idea :D I just played with the settings.
